# Save data from contentEditable div with mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli, contenteditable

I'm trying to save data from contentEditable div to mySql DB. But it seems that '+' symbol cannot be stored in DB. Is this right concept or am I missing something?

index.php

```
<div id="la_sent" contentEditable=true></div>
<button class="saveChanges">Save changes</button>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".saveChanges" ).click(function() {
      content = $('#la_sent').html();
      dataUrl = "iid=1&content="+content;
      $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:dataUrl,
        success:function(data){
            ...
      }});
  }); 
});
```

ajax.php

```
$type = $_POST['iid'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$mysqli=connect_database(); //connection to database
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE email_structure SET content = ? WHERE type = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $content, $type);
$ress = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
echo "OK";
```

For example: If I write in div element string 'a+b+c' it adds in DB string 'a b c '. Any idea why?

Comment: I changed it to GET and still same result.

Comment: Plus signs get replaced as spaces by default. Try passing `content` variable in your javascript through [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) first. `dataUrl = "iid=1&content="+encodeURIComponent(content);`

Comment: @Jeribo Thank you very much! That solved it :)

Comment: @Jeribo I think an answer would be most fitting to mark as solved ;-) good job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plus signs get replaced as spaces by default so you have to encode them first.

[encodeUriComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) is one way to do it in javascript

So editing your `script.js` to pass `content` variable through `encodeURIComponent` before appending it to `datUrl` should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".saveChanges" ).click(function() {
      content = $('#la_sent').html();
      dataUrl = "iid=1&content="+encodeURIComponent(content);  //encode content variable
      $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:dataUrl,
        success:function(data){
            ...
      }});
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I'm a serverside kind 'o guy myself. TBH, I'm re-learning JS stuff after a very long absence, and I've learned from this answer; *good job.* As a sidenote: It's definitely their use of jQuery that caused the issue. Had the OP not have used it, their query would have been successful.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I understand. Definitely more fun serverside:-) I do not think problem was with usage of jQuery since if I look on raw data(`file_get_contents("php://input");`) I can see plus sign in the URL. Just some funky bussiness serverside

Comment: I tested on my side using a prepared statement and turned out ok, for me anyway on UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

For security purposes, you should ALWAYS escape your text, before you plug it into your database (search with, store, etc.) See php's `mysqli_real_escape_string` to do this. Even though you are using prepared statements, you should still escape your characters.

If it's really a problem, you could replace the `+` with another character and, then replace it back when you are retrieving from the DB

Comment: huh? what do you call this? `UPDATE email_structure SET content = ? WHERE type = ?` it's a prepared statement. That doesn't resolve the question here.

Comment: I'm saying even though he is using prepared statements, he should still escape his characters

Comment: Well, replacing symbol + with other character is not clean solution.

Comment: Well, based on your data, you could do a number of things: Convert it to base64, encrypt it, but those would be signifigantly slower

Comment: Prepared statements remove the need for escaping input.

Comment: @JayBlanchard But escaping characters might be the solution to his problem anyway